# $L_p$ norm of a infinite sum

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, lp-spaces

For two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, we know that $|X_1+X_2|$$\le |X_1|+|X_2|$, where $|.|$ means the $L_p$ norm, by Minkowski’s inequality. To what extent, can this be extended to an infinite sum? Suppose that the infinite sum of $L_p$ norms is summable.

Comment: $|\sum X_n| \leq \sum |X_n|$ if $\sum X_n$ exist almost surely . This is immediate from Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: What happens when you try to prove this?  Maybe first work on series of numbers, $|\sum_n a_n| \le \sum_n|a_n|$. (Use the definition of convergence) Then go to normed space like $L_p$.

Comment: It's immediate if X's are real numbers. My question arises if they are random variables and |.| is L8 norm. I found Minkowski’s inequality but it's just for the sum of finite terms. My guess is this is true but just want to make sure.